# Total derivative of function that involves other terms

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $Q = q_1+ q_2 + .... +q_n$.

If there is function that is $f(Q)$ and we want to take total derivative, $\frac{df(Q)}{dQ}$, can we disect it into the terms that invole $q_n$, not $Q$?

Answer (score 1):

Just use chain rule
$$
\frac {\partial f}{\partial q_i} = \frac {df}{dQ} \frac {\partial Q}{\partial q_i} = \frac {df}{dQ}
$$